# $_GET / $_REQUEST different to string?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this library http://code.google.com/p/php-tail/

It's a great tool when it works but I'm stuck with some configuration.

Currently the file I'm tailing is set when constructing the class:

```
$tail = new PHPTail("example.log");
```

this works fine, so does

```
$log_file = "example.log";
$tail = new PHPTail($log_file);
```

What doesn't work (using URL localhost/tail.php?file=example

```
$log_file = $_GET['file'].".log";
$tail = new PHPTail($log_file);
```

Nor does

```
$log_file = $_REQUEST['file'].".log";
$tail = new PHPTail($log_file);
```

Even though the header of the page is set with the right log path, but the script doens't run.  I'm not seeing any PHP, JS or AJAX errors.

Comment: +1 Just for the *"it's a great tool when it works"*.

Comment: Have you already checked the actual value of `$log_file` with something like `var_dump($log_file)`?

Comment: Is something else going on here, like a URL rewrite discarding your query string?  `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: As @Gumbo already said, check the value of `$log_file`. If it's anything other than expected, try checking `var_dump($_GET)`, as @Michael suggested. This is basic debugging 101.

Comment: `var_dump($log_file)` gives me what I expect.

Comment: @jdborg: Then there's something else going wrong with code that's not shown here.

Comment: Yep, I agree.  Could you have a look at the code linked?

Comment: The source code for PHPTail is at [http://php-tail.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PHPTail.php](http://php-tail.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PHPTail.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just check your returned string man... how can you say it is the $GET or $REQUEST when you don't even give an output!

If it is anything it is definetly the way you pass the request!

Comment: Nope!  `var_dump($log_file)` gives me what I expect.